# Convert Physical Server 2008 R2 to VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines

I need to convert a Physical Server into a Hyper-V Virtual machine. I used the "Disk2vhd" Tool, but when uploading the image, it does not recognize the Operating System. I also used the "StarWind V2V Converter" tool, converting directly to a Hyper-v server, but when uploading the VM it did not upload. I use a Physical Server with Windows Server 2008 R2 with Raid1, Perc 6/i Controller.

Can anyone help me?

Att,

Jackson Pedrini

Comment: disk2vm is a common known Microsoft tool. 2008r2 is a dead horse, 2 reasons offtopic. Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Product recommendations are also off topic

Comment: Disks need to be made bootable. You omitted that. You  can use bootrec from your recovery environment started from your dvd to create the boot record on the disk.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIR, Starwinds V2V Converter has a Windows Repair Mode for converted images. It allows virtual machines to adapt to hardware automatically. Also, don't forget to put system into the maintenance mode. https://forums.starwindsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6231